# How do you find the path of a directory?

Tags: filesystems, find

How do you find the path of a directory?

Suppose I have directory called "pig-n.n.n"
I want to find the path to that directory.

I've tried : `find / -name "pig-n.n.n"`
and attained an unwanted result.

Comment: _"attained an unwanted result."_  What kind of unwanted result?  Were there two directories named `pig-n.n.n`?  Or something else?  If there were two, which one would you want?

Comment: What type of `pig` file did you download?  Was it `.tgz`?  `deb`?  `rpm`? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But if you limited the results to directories, it would improve:

```
find / -type d -name "pig-n.n.n"
```

(that may produce multiple results).

Given the followup, the instructions likely meant that there would be a directory with the **version** of `pig` as a suffix, e.g., "pig-4.3.2", and that you should use the actual version rather than "pig-**n.n.n**"

The most [recent release of `pig` is 0.16.0](http://pig.apache.org/releases.html#8+June%2C+2016%3A+release+0.16.0+available), so your directory name would be "pig-0.16.0" after downloading and unpackaging.

The instructions at [Apache](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/start.html) assume that you are going to unpack the pig program in a directory of your own choosing.  You *could* unpack it at the "/" level and (assuming the instructions are accurate) get a "/pig-0.16.0" directory.  More likely you will unpack it in a subdirectory someplace.

Using `find` can be slow.  You can do this fast by using the result from `pwd` inside the pig directory, e.g.,

```
cd pig-0.16.0 && pwd
```

(since there are no symbolic links mentioned in the instructions to confuse things).

Comment: I am following theses instructions (https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/start.html) to download pig. In step 3 it asks to put the location of pig to the path. However I I can't seem to fine the directory pig-n.n.n

name-VirtualBox:~$ find -iname "pig.properties"
    ./.linuxbrew/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.3/pig-0.16.0/conf/pig.properties
It should be

/pig-n.n.n/conf/pig.properties

Answer (score 1):

If the current directory has a file or directory named "pig-n.n.n", then, to get the complete path use `readlink`:

```
readlink -f  "pig-n.n.n"
```